# Wordpress action hook for post / page / product

Tags: wordpress

I need to add an action when a user displays a post_or_page_or_product(woocommerce product).
i tried to use

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );
```

it works... *too much*!
i mean that the function is invoked anytime a post is referenced (for a link in a widget for instance).
I need to invoke the function **only** when **the page** of the post_or_page_or_product is going to be displayed..
How to ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To limit to a set of post types you can use the `is_singular()` conditional tag:

```
add_action( 'init', 'so20270528_init' );
function so20270528_init()
{
    if( ! is_singular( array( 'post', 'page', 'product' ) ) )
        return;

    global $post;

    if( 'somevalue' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'somekey', true ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain well..  
i basically wish to enqueue some js and css depending on the custom fields of the post, but i need to add them only if the post is actually fully displayed..
with "the_post" hook it happens that the function is called for each post that get rendered in "recent posts" widget and other,  enqueuing all relative scripts and css

Comment: The `init` hook should be fine, I edited the answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 conditionals, one to **check the current landing page**, the other to check the **if the loop** that have_posts() **is the main loop**. This can simply be done with  the built in `in_the_loop()` conditional test:

```
function my_the_post_action($post){
    if(is_singular('product') && in_the_loop()) {
        // do some action
    }
}
add_action('the_post', 'my_the_post_action');
```

You can skip `return $post` as this action is passing `$post` by reference.

Note: using `&& is_main_query()` not working here as it will return `true` all the time.

In my case, I needed to modify a widget on blog archive page, that generated the exact same top posts as the blog page itself. The problem was they using the *same template-file* and needed to alter the `action 'the_post'`.

```
function my_the_post_action($post){
    if(is_home() && !in_the_loop()) {
        // do some action by examine the $post to find your widget posts
    }
}
add_action('the_post', 'my_the_post_action');
```